# Was the Furthest Mosque existent in the Prophet's time?

Tags: hadith

The following is taken from Ibn Sa'd's Al-Tabaqat Al-Kabir Volume I, English translation by S. Moinul Haq, M.A., PH.D assisted by H.K. Ghazanfar M.A. (Kitab Bhavan Exporters & Importers, 1784 Kalan Mahal, Daryaganj, New Delhi - 110 002 India):

> Muhammad Ibn 'Umar al-Aslami informed us; he said: Usamah Ibn Zayd al-Laythi related to me on the authority of 'Amr Ibn Shu'ayb, he on the authority of his father, he on the authority of his ('Amr's) grand-father; (second chain) he (Ibn Sa'd) said: Musa Ibn Ya'qub al-Zam'i related to me on the authority of his father, he on the authority of his (Musa's) grandfather, he on the authority of Umm Salamah; (third chain) Musa said: Abu al-Aswad related to me on the authority of 'Urwah, he on the authority of 'Ayishah; (fourth chain) Muhammad Ibn 'Umar said: Ishaq Ibn Hazim related to me on the authority of Wahb Ibn Kaysan, he on the authority of Abu Murrah the mawla of 'Aqil, he on the authority of Umm Hani daughter of Abu Talib (fith chain) he (Ibn Sa'd) said: 'Abd Allah Ibn Ja'far related to me on the authority of Zakariya Ibn 'Amr, he on the authority of Abu Mulaykah, he on the authority of Ibn 'Abbas and others; their consolidated narrations are: The Apostle of Allah, may Allah bless him, was taken by night on the seventeenth night of First Rabi' before Hijrah, and one year before the blockade in the mountainpass of Abu Talib, to Bayt al-Muqaddas. The Apostle of Allah, may Allah bless him, said: I was mounted on a beast whose size was between a donkey and a mule, with two wings in its thighs, which came up to its hoofs and were set in them. When I went near it to ride, it became restive. Thereupon Gabriel placed his hand on its head and said: O Buraq! are you not ashamed of what you are doing? By Allah no servant of Allah has ridden you before Muhammad, more honoured in the sight of Allah. It felt ashamed till it was covered with sweat, and became calm; then I mounted it. It moved its ears, and the earth shrank to such an extent that its hoofs (seemed to touch its surface) at the end of the range of our sight. It had a long back and long ears. Gabriel accompanied me and he never lost touch with me nor did I till we reached Bayt al-Muqaddas; and al-Buraq reached its halting place. It was tied there and it was the place where the beasts... of the Prophets were tied before the Apostle of Allah, may Allah bless him. He (the Prophet) said: I saw the Prophets who had assembled there for me. I saw Abraham, Moses and Jesus and, I thought there must be some one to lead them (in prayers); Gabriel made me go forward till I offered prayers in front of them and inquired from them (about their mission). They said: We were commissioned with Unity (of Allah).
>
> Some of them (narrators) said: The Prophet, may Allah bless him, had disappeared that night, so the members of family of 'Abd al-Muttalib went out to search him. Al-'Abbas went to Dhu Tuwa and began to shout: O Muhhamad! O Muhammad! The Apostle of Allah, may Allah bless him, said: I am here. He said: O my brother's son! You have worried the people since the (beginning of the) night, where had you been? He said: I am coming from Bayt al-Muqaddas. He said: In one night? He said: Yes. He said: Did you experience anything which was not good? He said: I did not experience anything but good. Umm Hani said: He was taken on this journey from our house. He slept that night with us; he offered al-'Isha prayers, and then he slept. When it was pre-dawn we awoke him (to offer) morning (prayers). He got up and when he offered morning prayers he said: O Umm Hani! I offered al'Isha prayers with you as you witnessed, then I reached Bayt Al-Muqaddas and offered prayers there; then I offered morning prayers before you. After this he got up to go out; I said to him: Do not relate this to the people because they will belie you and harm you. He said: By Allah I shall relate to them and inform them. They wondered at it and said: We have never heard a thing like this. The Apostle of Allah, may Allah bless him, said to Gabriel; O Gabriel! my people will not confirm it. He said: Abu Bakr will testify to it; and he is al-Siddiq. The narrator added: Many people who had embraced Islam and offered prayers went astray. (The Prophet continued,) I stood at al-Hijr, visualised Bayt al-Muqaddas and described its signs. Some of them said: HOW MANY DOORS ARE THERE IN THAT MOSQUE? I HAD NOT COUNTED THEM SO I BEGAN TO LOOK AT IT AND COUNTED THEM ONE BY ONE AND GAVE THEM INFORMATION CONCERNING THEM. I also gave information about their caravan which was on the way and its signs. They found them as I had related. Allah, the Almighty, the Great, revealed: "We appointed the vision which We showed thee as an ordeal for mankind". He (Ibn Sa'd) said: It refers to the vision of the eye which he saw with the eye. (pp. 246-248; bold and capital emphasis is mine)

According to history the temple mount was destroyed in 70 AD so how could it's features be described at this moment in time by the Prophet SAW?

Also the ahadith below seem to suggest an enclosing structure being present :

Narrated Zirr bin Hubaish:
"I said to Hudhaifah bin Al-Yaman: 'Did the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) perform Salat IN Bait Al-Maqdis?' He said: 'No.' I said: 'But he did.' He said: 'You say that, O bald one! Based upon what do you say that?' I said: 'Based upon the Qur'an, (the Judge) between you and I is the Qur'an.' So Hudhaifah said: 'Whoever argues using the Qur'an, then he has indeed succeeded.'" (One of the narrators) Sufyan said: "He means: 'He has indeed proven'" - and perhaps he (Sufyan) said: "He triumphed." He (Zirr) said: "Glorified is He Who took His slave for a journey by night from Al-Masjid Al-Haram to Al-Masjid Al-Aqsa (17:1).' He (Hudhaifah) said: 'Do you see (this proves that) he (ﷺ) performed Salat IN IT?' I said: 'No.' He said: 'If he had performed Salat IN IT, then it would have been required upon you that you perform Salat IN IT, just as it is required that you perform Salat in Al-Masjid Al-Haram.' (Jami' At-Tirmidhi, Book 47, Hadith 3440; bold and capital emphasis are mine)

'......I ENTERED the mosque and prayed two rak'ahs IN IT, and then CAME OUT and Gabriel brought me a vessel of wine and a vessel of milk......' (Sahih Muslim, Book 1, Hadith 318; bold and capital emphasis are mine)

(Note : the name "Bait al-Maqdis" is interchangeable and can refer to either Jerusalem or the Temple Mount depending on the context. When reading the second Hadith the context is clear that it refers to the Temple Mount since Masjid al-Haram is also mentioned.)

How can we understand the words ENTERED, IN IT & CAME OUT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temple was destroyed by the Romans this is also in Quran (Surah Al-Isra 7), however the ruins remained. Particularly parts of the wall surrounding it and hence the gates or entrances to the Temple Mount. There is nothing strange about the Prophet counting and describing these gates. I suggest reading through this: https://www.academia.edu/10860933/The_Haram_of_Jerusalem_324-1099_Temple_Friday_Mosque_Area_of_Spiritual_Power

Comment: Jazak Allahu Khayr thnx for that

Comment: I just edited the question with more things to address.

Answer (score 1):

You ask about this:

> ثُمَّ **دَخَلْتُ** الْمَسْجِدَ فَصَلَّيْتُ **فِيهِ** رَكْعَتَيْنِ
>   ثُمَّ **خَرَجْتُ** فَجَاءَنِي جِبْرِيلُ
>
> I **entered** the mosque and prayed two rak'ahs **in** it, and then **came out**

One can **enter**, **come out** of and be **in** a sacred precinct , without the need of an enclosing building with a roof. These expressions give no proof that the Prophet meant an enclosed building.

Take for example the Holy Land. Was Holy Land a building?

> O my people, **enter** the Holy Land which Allah has assigned to you and
>   do not turn back [from fighting in Allah 's cause] and [thus] become
>   losers."
>
> They said, "O Moses, indeed **within it** is a people of tyrannical
>   strength, and indeed, we will never **enter** it until they leave it; but
>   if they **leave** it, then we will **enter**."

Take example of Paradise. Is Paradise a building?

> The ones whom the angels take in death, [being] good and pure; [the
>   angels] will say, "Peace be upon you. **Enter** Paradise for what you used
>   to do."
>
> And as for those who were [destined to be] prosperous, they will be **in**
>   Paradise, abiding therein as long as the heavens and the earth endure,
>   except what your Lord should will - a bestowal uninterrupted.
>
> So We said, "O Adam, indeed this is an enemy to you and to your wife.
>   Then let him not **remove** you from Paradise so you would suffer

Also take the example of Masjid al-Haram. It had no roof and it did not even have walls at the time of the Prophet.

> Certainly has Allah showed to His Messenger the vision in truth. You
>   will surely **enter** al-Masjid al-Haram, if Allah wills, in safety,
>   with your heads shaved and [hair] shortened, not fearing [anyone]. He
>   knew what you did not know and has arranged before that a conquest
>   near [at hand].
>
> One prayer **in** the Sacred Mosque is better than one hundred thousand
>   prayers elsewhere (Sunan Ibn Majah)
>
> Umar asked the Prophet (ﷺ) "I vowed in the Pre-Islamic period of
>   ignorance to stay in I`tikaf for one night **in** Al-Masjid al-Haram." The
>   Prophet (ﷺ) said to him, "Fulfill your vow. (Sahih Bukhari)